# Implementing search bar in react using axios

Tags: spring-boot, react-redux, axios

How to create a separate search component in react with connecting it to the backend, spring boot application and how to deploy the search button to fetch data from json file.

Comment: What have you tried and what part do you need help with?

Comment: created a search bar need to connect it to backend and fetch data

Comment: You could use [thunk action](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) to fetch the data and in the component write a selector and effect to dispatch the action when search changes. Make sure you only render the result of the [last requested api call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751412/let-only-last-api-call-get-through)