# React: Set Value in a TextField

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

Back again with another react question!

**UserInfoStep.js** (Child)

```
    function UserInfoStep({ PUID, FirstName, handleChangeParent }) {
    const { dispatch } = useContext(ContactFormContext);

    return (
        //some controls

        <FormControl>
            <Grid container spacing={3}>

                <Grid item xs={12}>
                    <TextField required label="PUID"
                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                        name="PUID"
                        onChange={e =>
                            dispatch({ type: "PUID", payload: e.target.value })
                        }
                        value={PUID} variant="outlined" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>

            <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <TextField
                    required
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    label="First Name"
                    name="FirstName"
                    onChange={e =>
                        dispatch({ type: "FIRST_NAME_CHANGE", payload: e.target.value })
                    }
                    value={FirstName}

                    variant="outlined"
                />
            </Grid>
        </FormControl>
    );
}

export default UserInfoStep;
```

**ContactForm.js** (Parent)

```
    const initialState = {
    PUID: "",
    FirstName: "",
    total: 0
    //other params removed
};

function formReducer(state, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "PUID":
            fetch('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react')
                .then(result => result.json())
                .then(data => {

                    console.log(data.total);
                });
            return { ...state, PUID: action.payload };
        case "FIRST_NAME_CHANGE":
            return { ...state, FirstName: action.payload };
        default:
            throw new Error();
    }
}

function ContactForm() {
    const { PUID, FirstName, total } = state;


    const steps = [
        <UserInfoStep handleChangeParent={handleChange} {...{ PUID, FirstName }} />,
    ];

    return (
        <ContactFormContext.Provider value={{ dispatch }}>
    //some code removed

        </ContactFormContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default ContactForm;
```

I want to set the value returned from the API call `(data.total)`, in the FirstName input box when PUID onChange triggers. The API call can also be moved to the Child (UserInfoStep) if needed.

**Edit**

I have now moved my API call to UserInfoStep.js

```
const onPUIDChanged = (event) => {    
fetch('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=react')
  .then(result => result.json())
  .then(data => {        
    console.log(data.total);
  });
dispatch({ type: "PUID", payload: event.target.value });            
};


<Grid item xs={12}>
      <TextField required label="PUID"
      style={{width:'100%'}}
      name="PUID"
      onChange={onPUIDChanged}
      value={PUID} variant="outlined"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Reducers are not async so you have to use [thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) for redux or dispatch after fetch when you used useReducer (not clear what you are using). When you set async result on user input make sure you set the [last async result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62751846/1641941).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use API call in your reducer, the reducer is just a function that gets an `action` and returns the `state`.

The philosophy of using `action` - `reducer` - `store` in redux architecture is to separate the logic.

There are two options for you:

1. using a third library like `redux-saga` to control the async API calling and handle the side effects with the power of generators.
2. call the API in your component/page and then **dispatch** the proper action for success/failure cases.

Comment: option 2 seems feasible as I am a beginner :)

Comment: Now if I add FirstName = "ABC"; in onpuidchanged..it should be displayed in the firstname textfield?